# ViewPager with Fragments are Hidden

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i'm having a problem with ViewPager with Fragments.
in my app i have one fragment that inside it their's a ViewPager that each Fragment inside it have a ListView. each item on the ListView open another fragment that display more details about that item. 
so far so good, but when i popBackStack the FragmentManager the current fragment in the ViewPager is not seen.

and if i try to slide between the page i can see the next page and then slide back and see again the hidden page.

PageAdapter code:

```
private class SchedulePageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    JSONArray scheduleJsonArray;
    public SchedulePageAdapter(FragmentManager fm,JSONArray scheduleJsonArray) {
        super(fm);
        this.scheduleJsonArray = scheduleJsonArray;

    }



    @Override
    public ScheduleFragment getItem(int position) {
        ScheduleFragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        try {
            bundle.putString("json",scheduleJsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getJSONArray("channel_schedule").toString());
            bundle.putString("day",getArguments().getString("day"));
            bundle.putString("channel",channelTextView.getText().toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scheduleFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return scheduleFragment;
    }

    public JSONArray getScheduleJsonArray() {
        return scheduleJsonArray;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = scheduleJsonArray.length();
        return count;
    }

}
```

open item in listView:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        fragmentTransaction
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                .replace(R.id.mainFrameLayout, fullScheduleFragment, FullScheduleFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                .addToBackStack(PhoneMainActivity.MENU_STACK).commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use **`getChildFragmentManager()`** when you instanciate your **SchedulePageAdapter**

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new SchedulePageAdapter (getChildFragmentManager(), scheduleJsonArray);
        pagerData.setAdapter(adapter);
```

also use `getSupportFragmentManager` unstead :

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

if still dosn't work please leave a comment

Good luck